# How to use zustand devtools with typescript?

Tags: typescript, zustand

I am trying to use devtools feature of zustand. I am also using typescript. When I pass the store to devtools my whole store code throws error as: `Argument of type 'StateCreator<Store, [], [["zustand/devtools", never]], Store>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'StateCreator<Store, [], [], Store>'.`

Here is my store code:

```
const useUserStore = create<Store>(devtools((set) => ({
    token: "",
    isLogged: false,

    loginUser: (jwtToken: string) => {
        set((state) => ({
            ...state,
            token: jwtToken,
            isLogged: true,
        }));
    },

    logoutUser: () => {
        set((state) => ({
            ...state,
            token: "",
            isLogged: false,
        }));
    },
})));
```

Here is the Store type:

```
export type Store = {
    token: string;
    isLogged: boolean;
    loginUser: (jwtToken: string) => void;
    logoutUser: () => void;
};
```

Please guide me on how to resolve this error.

Comment: Related: [zustand#1013](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand/issues/1013#issuecomment-1160576940)

Answer (score 8):

Try changing `create<Store>(devtools...` to `create<Store>()(devtools...` (Note the extra pair of parentheses)

This is documented [on their Readme](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand#typescript-usage)

[image: Screenshot of documentation]